# How to suppress warnings messages in Rcpp/RcppArmadillo functions

Tags: rcpp, r-package, rcpparmadillo

I am using RcppArmadillo within an R package. I want to suppress a warning message that occurs in a C++ function due to numerical precision when a symmetric matrix fails a test of symmetry within `eig_sym()`. I am confident this is a precision issue as I have saved some of the matrices hitting this warning and tested them in R using `isSymmetric()` and they pass this.

I have tried including `#define ARMA_WARN_LEVEL 0` at the top of the header file where the function with this issue is defined, but this does not solve my issue and I am told `'ARMA_WARN_LEVEL' macro redefined` (presumably it is defined in the config file of `RcppArmadillo`).

Ideally I would suppress only errors associated with this call of `eig_sym`, but failing this I am content to suppress all warnings. If anyone can advise on how to effect this I would be very grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example?

Comment: probably you can check up a certain level of accuracy instead of turning them

Comment: From R documentation of [isSymmetric](https://rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/isSymmetric): "... test symmetry of matrices up to rounding error, using all.equal. _It might not be appropriate in all situations_." (emphasis added)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Armadillo's `config.hpp` -- the first header file included by Armadillo -- we see that it starts with

```
#if !defined(ARMA_WARN_LEVEL)
  #define ARMA_WARN_LEVEL 2
#endif
//// The level of warning messages printed to ARMA_CERR_STREAM.
//// Must be an integer >= 0. The default value is 2.
//// 0 = no warnings
//// 1 = only critical warnings about arguments and/or data which are likely to lead to incorrect results
//// 2 = as per level 1, and warnings about poorly conditioned systems (low rcond) detected by solve(), spsolve(), etc
//// 3 = as per level 2, and warnings about failed decompositions, failed saving/loading, etc
```

so a simple

```
#define ARMA_WARN_LEVEL 0
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
```

should take care of things.  We cannot "show" this as we have no reproducible example to work with.

Also note that there is a good reason why warnings are usually on.  They signal something you as author should be aware of.